# AWS EC2 Can't SSH to EC2 Created by Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a simple configuration with 7 subnets, 1 NAT, 3 public, 3 private.
All in eu-west-2, then in each availability zone.
The routing is simple, Private goes via NAT interface. Public via IGW.

I have a "proxy" server to SSH jump/tunnel that sat on the Public subnets with a public address.

**I can connect** to this server without issues.

The problem lies with then me trying to connect to the EC2 instance (created by EB) on the private subnet.

I've check the route tables and security which look fine (they are pretty simple) and I've use the same configuration many times before.

It looks as if the connection is connecting, but it just sits there, doesn't error.

Here is the output when i run it with `-vv` switch, which suggests the SSH connection is successful.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-10-1-135:~$ sudo ssh -vv -i "Mypem.pem" ec2-user@10.10.11.101

sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-10-1-135

OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.10.11.101" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.11.101 [10.10.11.101] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file Mypem.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file Mypem.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
```

Also, I've already checked the permissions on `Mypem.pem` with `chmod 400`.

It just sit (forever) on the line of debug above. Any help much appreciated - I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: Does the security group which was created for the EB instance allow inbound ssh connections?

Comment: @arudzinska yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 100% CPU

It took me ages to understand this, however on beanstalk it was picking up the application and hitting 100% CPU very quickly.

Because of the CPU I couldn't open an SSH session.

I hope this helps someone else in the future!